# Show that there exist only $n$ solutions

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n>1$ with integer coefficients, and let $k$ be a positive integer. Consider the polynomial $Q(x) = P( P ( \ldots P(P(x)) \ldots ))$, where $P$ occurs $k$ times. Prove that there are at most $n$ integers $t$ such that $Q(t)=t$.

**Source: IMO 2006, #5**.

I know it can't be this easy, but this is what I came up with.

$Q(t) = t$ shows that $P(t) = t$ and $P(P(t)) = t$, let

$r(x) = P(x) - x$ then $\deg r(x) = \deg P(x) = n \ge 2$.

Suppose there are $\ge n + 1$ solutions for $Q(t) = t$, consider them $t_1, t_2, ..., t_n, t_{n+1}$

Consider the least case: There are $n+1$ solutions for $Q(t) = t$.

Hence, $t_1, t_2, t_3, .. , t_n, t_{n+1}$ all satisfy $P(t) = t$.

The roots of $r(x)$ are $t_1, t_2, ..., t_{n+1}$ (from the assumption), which means $r(x)$ has at least $n+1$ solutions, contrary to the fundamental theorem of algebra and the given that $P(x)$ has degree $n$.

Comment: No, $Q$ has degree $nk$ and thus as many solutions. Roots of $P(t)=t$ are roots of $Q(t)=t$, but not the other way round. There will be cycles of roots where $t_{j+1}=P(t_j)$ and $t_k=t_0$ with not all of them equal.

Comment: @LutzL, then how can I prove it?

Comment: Consider the polynomial $P(x)=1-x^2$. Then $P(P(x))= x^2(2-x^2)$ which has three distinct real roots (but only one of those is an integer). What does it mean? It means that if in our proof we don't mention integers, our proof is not correct. In particular, your proof is not correct.

Comment: @LutzL $Q$ in general will have degree $n^k$, and hence may have considerably more solutions. Rest of your points are valid of course...

Comment: **Hint:**  You can use the well known property for integers $a, b \in \mathbb Z \implies (a-b) \mid (P(a)-P(b))$.  Using this, we can reduce all odd $k$ to the case $k=1$, and even $k$ to $k=2$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be the set of integer roots of $Q(x)=x$.  If possible, let $|R| > n> 1$.  Let $x_0 \in R$, and denote $x_{i+1}=P(x_i)$.  Then we may note $x_k = x_0$ and all $x_i \in R$.

Now $a, b \in \mathbb Z \implies (a-b) \mid (P(a)-P(b))$.  Using this, we can establish a chain:
$$(x_1-x_0) \mid (x_2-x_1) \mid \cdots \mid (x_k-x_{k-1}) \mid (x_1-x_0)$$
$$\implies \forall \; i, j\quad |x_{i+1}-x_i| = |x_{j+1}-x_j| $$

Further, as $\sum_i (x_i-x_{i-1}) = 0$, we must either have the possibility that $x_i = x_j$ for all $i, j$, or there are an equal number of positive and negative terms being summed (which is possible only for even $k$).

In the first possibility, (which is the only case for odd $k$, and essentially is the case $k=1$), we must have $\forall x_0 \in R, \;P(x_0) = x_0$, so the $n$th degree polynomial $P(x)-x$ has $|R|> n$ roots, which is impossible.

Otherwise, we must have at least one link in the chain above where the sign reverses, i.e. there is some $j$ s.t. $x_j-x_{j-1} = x_j-x_{j+1} \implies x_{j-1}=x_{j+1} \implies (P\circ P)(x_{j-1}) = x_{j-1}$, so every alternate term must be the same.  Thus $\forall x_0 \in R, \; (P \circ P)(x_0) = x_0$.  This is essentially the base case $k=2$.

For case $k=2$:  $\forall r \in R$, if $P(r) = r$, then this is again case $k=1$.  Else, let $P(s) \neq s$ for some $s \in R$.  Then for any $r \in R$, we can construct the chains:
$$(r-s) \mid (P(r) - P(s)) \mid (r - s) \implies |r-s| = |P(r)-P(s)|$$
$$(r-P(s)) \mid (P(r) - s) \mid (r - P(s)) \implies |r-P(s)| = |P(r) - s|$$

Together this gives $P(r)+r=C$, some constant irrespective of $r$, whence the $n$th degree polynomial $P(x)+x-C$ has all $r \in R$ as roots, which leads to a contradiction when $|R|> n$.